# Host a blog engine in my wordpress site

Tags: blog-page

Hi I have a website like www.shankpress.com, it is wordpress v3,  and i want my users to have blogs hosted in my site and have url like: blogs.shaknpress.com...and I can show who got the most popular blog entry etc...

users can openly register, create a blog, start blogging and so on ...

I am willing to buy solutions if no free stuff is available...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run multiple blogs on single installation of WordPress you need to enable and configure `multisite` functionality, see [Create a Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).

While that will take care of basics, managing network of blogs controlled by users (rather than single admin/team) reliably and securely will likely require much more research and work.

Comment: +1 to the "reliably and securely will likely require much more research and work"

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at wordpress MU - it will have all the functionalities you need

There is also an easy but more "manual way" 
if in your hosting, you have some tools like fantastico or webkits or something, usually they have a tool that automatically installs wordpress.

what you have to do is

- create a subdomain
- install wordpress on it
- email your users their details

so it depends on how many users you have installed and on how techy/how much you willing to spend time on it

Comment: WP MU is deprecated since 3.0... It got merged into WP.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about MU when I was asking, its good to now its deprecated.